# Truncate decimal for MySql Command

Tags: mysql, decimal, truncate, inner-query

I want to use Truncate command with Select * query . I am thinking if something like a nested query is applicable just to determine if the returned column is a decimal value or not and apply truncate (2 decimal point) to it.
A random version would look something like following -

```
Select * from my_Table ( Truncate if column = intiger)
```

Please provide pointers as on how to develop such kind of Query.

Comment: So you are not actually sure what data types different columns have, but still want to use `SELECT *` and apply TRUNCATE to all columns that are integers?

Comment: Yes , Select * to get all the data but truncate those value which are having decimal values.